# How to get individual values of radio buttons that are added dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button

I have a drop down that's numbered 1-30. So if I select '2', my radio buttons will appear like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="yes-sdf-1" name="field[1][sdfradio]" value="Yes" />
<input type="radio" id="no-sdf-1" name="field[1][sdfradio]" value="No" />

<input type="radio" id="yes-sdf-2" name="field[2][sdfradio]" value="Yes" />
<input type="radio" id="no-sdf-2" name="field[2][sdfradio]" value="No" />
```

How do I get the individual values of the radio buttons because I want to set conditions that will only affect those with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to give you an idea.

Try this:

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

This will return the `name` of the radio button.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbmS4/1)**